# How to convert the pdf file to jpeg images

Tags: python

Here is my program, I want to convert pdf file into jpeg images, I wrote below code I am getting the `PIL.PpmImagePlugin` object how can I convert to `jpeg` format can you please help me. Thank you in advance.

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
images = convert_from_path('/home/cioc/Desktop/testingFiles/pdfurl-guide.pdf')
print images
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an output path and an output format for the images. Each page of your pdf will be saved in that directory in the specified format.

Add these keyword arguments to your code.

```py
images = convert_from_path(
    '/home/cioc/Desktop/testingFiles/pdfurl-guide.pdf',
    output_folder='img',
    fmt='jpeg'
)
```

This will create a directory named `img` and save each page of your pdf as a jpeg image inside `img/`

**Alternatively**, you can save each page using a loop by calling `save()` on each `image`.

```py
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


images = convert_from_path('/home/cioc/Desktop/testingFiles/pdfurl-guide.pdf')

for page_no, image in enumerate(images):
    image.save(f'page-{page_no}.jpeg')
```

Comment: i want to save these images into existing folder path('/home/cioc/Desktop/testingFiles)

Comment: @gowthami You can use `output_folder='/home/cioc/Desktop/testingFiles` in the kwargs. The 2nd part of my answer where I'm calling `.save()` on each image will save the images in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pdf2image` parameter `fmt='jpeg'` to make it return JPEG instead.

You can also just manipulate the PPM as a you would a normal JPEG as this is only the backend file type. If you do `Image.save('path.jpg')` it will save it as a JPEG.